# HttpClient - limit on query string?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am suppose to use an existing framework which only serves get requests. And the client side code also just makes a get request using Httpclient to perform certain look-ups.
Till now everything works fine as the get request query parameters were not too long.
I am trying to use the same above setup, but my query sting will grow too long. 
Sample query for get command will look like : may grow to 70K numbers

`http://server.com?id=xx&num=123,12,31,22,23,24,.....`

So i was wondering if there is any limit on the query length in HttpCient get method. Will it be the similar way as we have the get request query limits in normal browsers IE,FF ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpClient can be optionally configure to set a max limit on HTTP header length. It does not specifically put a limit on the length of the request URI or its query component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did some testing with 70k characters in query string and they were handled fine on the server. So seems like no limits. Thanks for confirming it.